# Word replace mechanism

Tags: microsoft-word, special-characters

I have a document in Word (Hebrew language). Many words in the document end with apostrophe (’), and I need to replace it with the character (').
However, when I"m trying to do so via the Word "Find and Replace" dialog, I get the same (’) result, i.e., the character replaced by the old character (I checked that the character is replaced by "track changes"). 
Why? What can I do to solve it?

Comment: One useful workflow is to copy the character from a known-good source.  I have done similar things with whitespace characters (tabs, spaces, carriage returns).  I can't tell from the dialog here if an Answer was found, but by all means give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `File | Options | Proofing/Auto Correct Options | AutoFormat As You Type`, and then uncheck replacing `Straight quotes with smart quotes`.  Then, run your Find/Replace again.

I just tested this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

https://word.tips.net/T007450_Replacing_Some_Smart_Quotes.html

Straight Quotes with Smart Quotes option should be cleared in this case

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  If you accept an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, that will indicate the problem is solved.  However, please expand this answer to include the essential information from the link so that the answer is self-contained. Links rot over time, in which case your solution wouldn't remain helpful to other readers with a similar problem.  Or, since tmsdajpa already posted the same solution with instructions, you could just delete this answer to avoid duplication.  :-)